# Cordova ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

When trying to send my app to app store, I'm receiving the following message:
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

But my simulator log shows

```
2021-05-21 14:05:47.333578-0300 xxx[21780:432427] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume

**2021-05-21 14:05:47.333667-0300 xxx[21780:432427] Using WKWebView**

2021-05-21 14:05:47.333880-0300 xxx[21780:432427] [CDVTimer][console] 0.035048ms

2021-05-21 14:05:47.334027-0300 xxx[21780:432427] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.043988ms


2021-05-21 14:05:47.334811-0300 xxx[21780:432427] Unlimited access to network resources

2021-05-21 14:05:47.334912-0300 xxx[21780:432427] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 0.808954ms

2021-05-21 14:05:47.335034-0300 xxx[21780:432427] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.040054ms

2021-05-21 14:05:47.335149-0300 xxx[21780:432427] WARNING: NativeXHR is allowing untrusted certificates due to preference AllowUntrustedCerts=on

2021-05-21 14:05:47.335628-0300 xxx[21780:432427] [CDVTimer][cdvwkwebviewfilexhr] 0.518084ms

2021-05-21 14:05:47.335701-0300 xxx[21780:432427] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 1.880050ms

2021-05-21 14:05:47.447104-0300 xxx[21780:432427] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process xxx

2021-05-21 14:05:47.447297-0300 xxx[21780:432427] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)

2021-05-21 14:05:47.447437-0300 xxx[21780:432427] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

I've already tried updating my plugins, and the plugins list is:

```
cordova-plugin-cleartext 1.0.0 "CordovaPluginsCleartext"

cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"

cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"

cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.2.2 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"

cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr 3.0.0 "Cordova WKWebView File XHR Plugin"

cordova-sqlite-storage 6.0.0 "Cordova SQLite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
```

Tried adding wkwebview to config.xml as well.

Any other thing I could look into?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova has already deprecated the WKWebView usage. So in order to fix those and future issues update cordova version to 10 and android/ios projects to newest.

Android 9.1
Ios 6.2

Here is the deprecation message: https://cordova.apache.org/2021/02/07/deprecate-wkwebview-engine.html

Comment: Tried it. It works on my emulator and with my testers, but the app got rejected with
"We discovered one or more bugs in your app. Specifically, your app loaded indefinitely when we attempted to create a new account. Please review the details below and complete the next steps."
Any idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: @awkngg this is absolutely other issue, not the one you described in the title. Seems like you app freezes/crashes when testers from apple try to create account in your app. Mb you have some connection restrictions on your server, or IP filter or something else - it might be a bundle of things